# SD card in Android virtual device

Tags: sd-card

I have created an Android virtual device with sd-card.

Now I want to create another Android virtual device with sd-card with same data.

**Where can I find the sd-card image file?**

By the way, I'm using Eclipse Juno on Windows 8.

Comment: Not being familiar with Eclipse: Is your question about a problem with your Android device, or is it rather a development thingy? Your question is not clear to me in this regard.

Comment: @Izzy: Not related to android device. Strictly related to development.

Comment: Ooops... In that case: sorry, development questions are off topic here (see our [FAQ], we are a user-oriented Q&A site). To find a good place for your issue, I recommend checking [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) -- which lists a lot of good ressources. Remember though you're always welcome here with questions from a user's standpoint, as described by our [FAQ] :)

Comment: I think this question is okay to stay here. I can imagine a power user using an Android emulator needing this information.

Comment: I agree with @AlEverett it is possible a non-developer might find this information useful.

Comment: You're welcome -- though the bigger thanks belongs to John it seems :) And @AlEverett yes, agreed. Just as soon as Eclipse comes into play, it's rather a developer -- but true, the answer could be useful to power-users as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

### Clean way

Your SD card image is stored in the following location:

```
~/.android/avd/<avd name>.avd/sdcard.img
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680992/in-avd-emulator-how-to-see-sdcard-folder-and-install-apk-to-avd

So, if your AVD is named SCREEN_LARGE, then your image file would be at:

```
~/.android/avd/SCREEN_LARGE.avd/sdcard.img
```

I am using a Mac but I'm sure the location for the .android folder should be inside of your 'User' folder as well.

You can then duplicate this file and then use it with another AVD.

### Less clean way

copy all of your files/folders that you want off of the old image from ADB:

```
adb pull <dir or file>
```

- [How to use adb pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull)

---

Then, using ADB create a brand new Image:

```
mksdcard <size> <file>
```

mksdcard can be found in the  tools/ directory of your sdk folder.

---

Then load the AVD with the new image:

```
emulator -sdcard <filepath>
```

---

Once the AVD has loaded your new image, you can then push your files:

```
adb push <dir or file>
```

---

info taken from Google page:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sdcard

I hope this helped!